# Google Calendar API - Access own calendar via Service account

Tags: python, api, authentication, calendar, google-api-python-client

I want to access the Google Calendar API to insert entries with Python. I created a **Service account** on the Google API console, added an private key, downloaded it.

But when I try to modify anyting of my calendar, it is on the same account, I get the following error message. Reading works.

Code is

```
import httplib2

from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials 
from apiclient.discovery import build

event = {
         'summary' : 'Appointment',
         'location' : 'Somewhere',
         'start' : {
                    'dateTime' : '2012-09-03T10:00:00.000-07:00'
                    },
         'end' :    {
                 'dateTime' : '2012-09-03T10:25:00.000-07:00'
                    }
}


f = file("key.p12", "rb")
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
                                                service_account_name='423291807109-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
                                                private_key=key,

                                                scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'                                            
                                            )

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
request = service.events().insert(calendarId='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com', body=event)

response = request.execute()

print(response)
```

Error message is:

```
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com/events?alt=json returned "Forbidden">
```

I would have thought that I can access my own data with this service account, but it seems not to be.

Google claims that

> After the Service Account has been created, you will also have access
>   to the client ID associated with the private key. You will need both
>   when coding your application. - 
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2?hl=de#scenarios

I googled about 2 hours, but it seems to be documented very bad. Is there a way I can insert new events via the Google Calendar API without user interaction (aka 3-legged OAuth) or is there a way to fix it?

I just found deprecated ClientLoging. Why does Google makes it that difficult?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that 3-stepped OAuth works if one dumps the resulting credentials to JSON and reads them in every time you need them.

So the flow is:
Add your **client_secrets.json** as stated on [Google API](http://bit.ly/NKrI0S) in the same folder as this script. Grab the key from the url given in the prompt. Enter it on request to the prompt. Party!11. I hope these credentials last forever.

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',
                               scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                               redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print('Visit this site!')
print(auth_uri)
code = raw_input('Insert the given code!')
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
print(credentials)

with open('credentials', 'wr') as f:
    f.write(credentials.to_json())
```

Now, in the application itself:

```
def __create_service():
    with open('credentials', 'rw') as f:
        credentials = Credentials.new_from_json(f.read())

    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    return build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
```

To get a service object, one can now call

```
service = __create_service()
```

and use the API on it.

Comment: i have followed ur solution and my credentials are noe in the file. Can you please tell me how can i load those from that file and then use `credentials.authorize()`.

Comment: I wrote an example long ago, you can find it on https://github.com/Rentier/ReindeerIkenga