# Google Calendar API - service account - without google apps domain

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

Is it possible to use Google Calendar API v3 with service accounts without having a google apps domain?

Basically what i want to do is create an event on my own calendar with a python script without having the script to prompt me for the user and password... anyone has any idea?

I used this code, but no luck:

```
import pprint
import pytz
import httplib2
import requests

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

with open('/home/xpto/service_account_certificate.pem', 'rb') as f:
  key = f.read()

service_account_name = '000000000000-j...@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    service_account_name,
    key,
    scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'],
    sub='xpto@gmail.com')

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http)
```

I get this error:

auth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Unauthorized client or scope in request

Comment: btw - do you have a python script which prompts for a user and password and is able to modify the user's calendar? I would be interested in seeing that!

Answer (score 1):

Yes - just create a service account and this will give you an email address for the account.

Then just share your calendar with that email address giving it whatever permissions it needs.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. I get this error: auth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Unauthorized client or scope in request.

Comment: I have a script which works with scope = calendar.readonly. Of course, that won't let you create an event. Another possibility is to use the api calls to create a calendar owned by the service account and then share it with your account.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve my problem reading this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252644/google-calendar-api-access-own-calendar-via-service-account . So instead of using a service account, i've used a normal account and used the script at the end of that post to retrieve and write the access token. I've been using it for one week now and has not expired... But i can't find anywhere if the token will expire or not and when.

Answer (score 0):

Granting access of google resources to the service account works. In my case, I was trying to use a service account to push files onto google drive. By granting access of the folder on my google drive to the service account (email), I was able to see files and create files on google drive under my account.